# На что конкретно указывает итератор end() в std::list? C++

Tags: c++, list, указатели, итераторы, linked-list

Итератор end(), если верить документации, указывает на место после последнего элемента в контейнере. То есть на участок памяти ПОСЛЕ последнего элемента контейнера. Если с такими структурами как вектор, где память расположена последовательно, это легко представить, то на что указывает end() в списках, где элементы могут быть разбросаны по памяти?

Comment: Не стоит воспринимать это буквально, он туда указывает *логически*. А так в этом итераторе может хранится специальное значение-заглушка или он может указывать от элемент- заглушку, или еще что-нибудь.

Comment: @user7860670 то есть сам указатель внутри итератора может быть nullptr, например, а итератор сам "абстрактно" обозначает (слово обозначает тогда лучше подходит и не вводит в заблуждение) место после последнего элемента?

Comment: На самом деле там даже не обязательно лежит указать, я видел реализации, где там лежали ссылки на контейнер и дескриптор элемента.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Итераторы, содержащие значение *past-the-end* не могут быть разыменованы (для них нельзя вызывать `operator*`), поэтому говорить о том, что они вообще указывают на какое-то место в памяти некорректно.

Если же глянуть на конкретную реализацию, например, MS, то можно увидеть следующее:

```
_NODISCARD iterator begin() noexcept {
    return iterator(_Mypair._Myval2._Myhead->_Next, _STD addressof(_Mypair._Myval2));
}

_NODISCARD iterator end() noexcept {
    return iterator(_Mypair._Myval2._Myhead, _STD addressof(_Mypair._Myval2));
}
```

Т.е. первый элемент ассоциирован с неким `head->next`, а *past-the-end* с `head`.

Также стоит заметить, что для пустого контейнера должно выполняться условие `begin() == end()`. А значит `head->next == head`. Т.о. в кокретной реализации `std::list::end()` указывает на некоторую "голову" списка, при этом сама "голова" является не элементом списка, а неким внутренним специальным значением.

Comment: Т.о. (на первый взгляд) мы имеем ту же организацию списков, что и в ядре линукса. Кольцевой двунаправленный список, где один из элементов является головой. Указатель next из него рассматривается как указатель на первый элемент списка, а prev -- на последний. Естественным образом указатель next у последнего будет указывать на эту голову.